# Need batch file to remove old versions of file

Tags: batch-file

I am using a program which saves the data with a version tag.  I would like to write a batch file that remove all but the latest version.
For example the filenames could be:
   2355-55-1034.dat,
   2355-55-1123.dat,
   2355-55-1200.dat
I want to remove all except the newest one.
   Thanks HD

Comment: ( old number old date ?)

Answer (score 0):

**in cmd :**

```
FOR /F %I IN ('DIR 2355-55*.dat /B /aa /O:-D') DO COPY %I c:\r\ & EXIT
```